# conversion of space separated string to coma separated in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting

I am indenting to convert a string like:

```
abc def ghi
```

to

```
"abc","def","ghi"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
testvar= "abc def ghi"

a='"';

res="";
coma=","
for i in $testvar
do
vals=(${i//__/ })
 if [ -z "$res" ]; then
    $res= $res$a$vals$a
 else 
 $res=$res$coma$a$vals$a
 fi
done

echo $res
```

Its giving this error:

```
$bash -f main.sh

main.sh: line 4: abc def ghi: command not found
```

What wrong am I doing?
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Check out the answer to a similar questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I am trying to do a bit diff thing, I have already used the split syntax from the link in vals=(${i//__/ })

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way by creating an array and using IFS. Loop through every value and add double qoutes around it.

```
array=($testvar)

declare item
for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
    item="${array[$idx]}"
    array[$idx]=\""${item}"\"    # Add double qoute
done

(IFS=, ; echo "${array[*]}")   # prevents IFS from changing.
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `sed` command like below:
(notice that there are multi spaces in `def` and `ghi`)

```
$ echo 'abc def   ghi' | sed -E 's/\s+/\,/g'
abc,def,ghi
```